# How to enable bluetooth for Dell Inspiron Laptop?

Tags: 12.04, dell, bluetooth

How do I enable Bluetooth for my Dell Inspiron laptop? It tells no adapters found.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please give more details, so people can help you. Try to find out what is the exact brand and model of your bluetooth chip. Depending on how it's connected to your mainboard, you might find it in the output of the lspci or lsusb command (or probably more easy: the user manual of your notebook).

Comment: attach the output of "rfkill list all" might be bluetooth adapter is not found by ubuntu.

Comment: first check if it has a bluetooth module - on some of these the adapter can be found in a small compartment under the battery, please provide you model for more information - http://www.instructables.com/id/Dell-E1505-Bluetooth-Upgrade/ - as some of these were shipped with out the module but still have the led and keyshortcut

Comment: My Dell Inspiron Laptop came preinstalled with Ubuntu 12.04. Bluetooth did not work, sound was crappy....I reinstalled Ubuntu, without any Dell repositories and everything worked like a charm. What I want to say is, if this is a new laptop, update to at least 14.04....

Answer (score 1):

Open an terminal and type

```
rfkill list all
```

If the bluetooth is shown in the list,run

```
rfkill unbound bluetooth
```

This should activate the bluetooth.

But if the bluetooth is disabled by hardware switch,this command won't work. If so , read the laptop manual to know the hardware switch for bluetooth and then activate it.

Answer (score 0):

May be bluetooth is disabled by hardware switch. Press the hardware switch again to enable it. In DELL Inspiron, normally the hardware switch is along with <kbd>F2</kbd> (above <kbd>2</kbd>). If function keys are toggled you have to press <kbd>Fn+F2</kbd>. After pressing the key waits for some seconds and if no response press again.

Answer (score 0):

previously i was having the same issue , just restart your pc and boot into windows then switch on your bluetooth by long pressing F2 and then again restart and boot into Ubuntu .

it will automatically finds the adapter and you will be able to switch it on.

Comment: Thanks.... I dont have windows with me. Will this work in ubuntu? If not any alternatives?

Comment: the problem is its not detecting your bluetooth adapter . So i dont have any alternative .this is the only way i know ..